# perl - access elements in hash of arrays of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures

I have the following hash of arrrays of arrays in perl

```
$VAR1 = {
      'A' => [
                   [
                     '1',
                     'PRESENT_1',
                     'ABSENT_2',
                   ],
                   [
                     '2',
                     'PRESENT_1',
                     'ABSENT_2',
                   ]
                 ],
      'B' => [
                  [
                    '5',
                    'PRESENT_1',
                    'ABSENT_2',
                  ],
                  [
                    '6',
                    'PRESENT_1',
                    'ABSENT_2',
                  ],
                  [
                    '7',
                    'ABSENT_1',
                    'PRESENT_2',
                  ]
                ]
    };
```

I want to access the first element from each small array and print it to the console.

So the output should look like this

```
EL 1
EL 2
EL 5
EL 6
EL 7
```

I'm having difficulties with looping through the arrays and dereferencing. I've started like this, but that's clearly not the correct way

```
my %hash = %{ $VAR1 };
for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
   for my $arr1 (@{ $hash{$key} }){
       for my $arr2 (@{ $arr1}) {
            print "EL ", @{ $arr2 }[0], "\n";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: The [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) page (Perl Data Structures Cookbook) has lots of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's close.

Iterate over elements (this also prints out the first one, separately)

```
my %hash = %{ $hashref };
for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
   for my $arrayref (@{ $hash{$key} }) {
       say "First element: ", $arrayref->[0];
       for my $elem (@$arrayref) {
            say "element: $elem";
       }
    }
}
```

(need to say `use feature qw(say);` somewhere on top, for [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/feature) [say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say))

So for the first element alone -- if that's indeed all you need -- there is no need for the inner loop at all

---

Then, just for an exercise, for the first element alone one can also do

```
say $_->[0] for map { @{$hash{$_}} } sort keys %hash;
```

And since we're manipulating lists out of arrayrefs let's mention [postfix dereferencing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax), available since v5.20 and stable in v5.24

```
use feature qw(postderef);

say $_->[0] for map { $hash{$_}->@* } sort keys %hash;
```

It doesn't buy us much here but then again here it's clear what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $VAR1 = {
      'A' => [
                   [
                     '1',
                     'PRESENT_1',
                     'ABSENT_2',
                   ],
                   [
                     '2',
                     'PRESENT_1',
                     'ABSENT_2',
                   ]
                 ],
      'B' => [
                  [
                    '5',
                    'PRESENT_1',
                    'ABSENT_2',
                  ],
                  [
                    '6',
                    'PRESENT_1',
                    'ABSENT_2',
                  ],
                  [
                    '7',
                    'ABSENT_1',
                    'PRESENT_2',
                  ]
                ]
    };
    
my %hash = %{ $VAR1 };
print Dumper(\%hash);

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    foreach my $inner (@{$hash{$key}}){
        print "EL ".@$inner[0]."\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
EL 1
EL 2
EL 5
EL 6
EL 7
```